# Python latest release 2.7 shows SSL error

Tags: python-2.7

I have downloaded & installed python latest 2.7 version (on date - 16th July). Initially i was unable to install even pip using cmd - `python get-pip.py`, somehow i managed to installed pip. Then i was unable to install any package using pip. It throws SSL error. Tried multiple ways to install but no go. No proxy or admin issues observed (admin confirmed the same). 
Then i uninstalled & reinstalled 2.7.10 which resolved the issue. Please check the issue and resolve it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly because of old unstable version, used 2.7.10 and then everything worked.